# running server with a specific unit test in c#

Tags: c#, rest, unit-testing

I want to unit test the client, which, requires that the server be running
Is there some way to specify in the unit test project that the server project should be started before running a particular unit test?

Comment: I will mock the server in my unit test and make my client test independent from the server

Comment: If your test requires you to start a server, it is **not** a unit test; it is an integration or system test. If you'd like to make it a unit test, mock your external dependency appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the server implementation, but you should be able to start a server instance at the beginning of the test or Mock the server to test your class.

Publish the class to test for a better and more accurate answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make an integration test, you could use a `TestServer`.

Here are some resources

- [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [this](https://klucyszy.github.io/howto/2021/12/17/how-to-create-integration-tests-in-net-6.html) blog post has a decent explanation as well